# When I try to execute my script the console on replit just doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I am very new to Javascript so please bear with me! When I try to execute my script it doesnt respond! It just keeps dropping on to the next line waiting for me to write node index.js AGAIN. I have posted 2 images in the Imgur album, the first one is me writing node index.js and the second is me pressing enter and the response. Literally blank.
I would like some help as I feel like this is the last step to get my bot up and running! :D.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilvpu.jpg

Here is my index.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const {token} = require('./token.json');
var jsonconfig = require("./config.json")
var jsonconfig,DISCORD_ID
var CMDS = jsonconfig.CMDS

var prefix = 'p!'
client.on("message", message => {
var args = message.content.split(" ")
args.forEach((a, b) => {
  args[b] = a.replace("`", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(".", "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace("`", "")
  args[b] = args[b].replace(`"`, "")

  args[b] = args[b].replace(`'`, "")

})
var args = message.content.split(" ")
if (message.author.bot == false) {
  if (message.content.startsWith("$")) {

    if (message.channel.id != CMDS && message.author.id != DISCORD_ID) {
      message.reply("stop using cmds here idiot. <#" + CMDS + ">")
      return;
    }
  }

  args.forEach((a, b) => {
    args[b] = a.replace("`", "")
    
    args[b] = args[b].replace(".", "")

    args[b] = args[b].replace("`", "")
    args[b] = args[b].replace(`"`, "")

    args[b] = args[b].replace(`'`, "")

        })
  switch (args[0]) {
    
    case prefix + "pois":

  var id = parseInt(args[1])
  if (id) {
    fetch(`https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/` + id).then(res => res.text()).then(res => {
      //// clog(res)
      if (res != 'Uaid not found, try again later') {
        var search = res,
          first = 'uaid_details'
        var second = `owner_list`;
        var itemdat = JSON.parse(search.substring(search.indexOf(first) + first.length, search.indexOf(second)).replace(";", "").replace("=", "").replace("var", ''))
        // clog(itemdat)
        var search = res,
          first = 'item_details'
        var second = `uaid_details`;
        var itemname = JSON.parse(search.substring(search.indexOf(first) + first.length, search.indexOf(second)).replace(";", "").replace("=", "").replace("var", ''))
        var search = res,
          first = 'owner_list'
        var second = `lucky_cat_uaid`;
        var owners = JSON.parse(search.substring(search.indexOf(first) + first.length, search.indexOf(second)).replace(";", "").replace("=", "").replace("var", ''))
        message.reply(`Checking be patient bozo...`)
        var em = new discord.messageEmbed()
        .setFooter("Archs")
      .setURL("https://www.rolimons.com/item/" + args[1])
        .setColor("#ffc0cb")
        .setThumbnail("https://www.roblox.com/thumbs/asset.ashx?width=420&height=420&assetid=" + itemdat["asset_id"])
        .setTitle(`UAID ` + args[1])
        .setURL(`https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/` + args[1])
        .setAuthor(itemname.name, `https://www.roblox.com/thumbs/asset.ashx?width=420&height=420&assetid=` + itemdat["asset_id"])
      if (itemdat.serial) {
        em.addField('SERIAL', itemdat.serial)
          }
        em.addField('OWNER', (itemdat.owner_name || `Hidden/Deleted`))
        em.addField(`Last Traded`, itemdat["updated_relative_string"])
        message.reply(em)
        if (itemdat["updated_relative_string"].search(`month`) != -1 || itemdat["updated_relative_string"].search(`year`) != -1) {
          message.channel.send(`Since the current owner has had it for more than a month, we have deemed this uaid(${args[1]}) as CLEAN :white_check_mark:`)
          } else {
          comped_detected = false
          Object.keys(owners).forEach(x => {
            var item = owners[x][0]
            if (item && parseInt(x) + 2628000 >= Date.now() / 1000) {
              fetch(`https://avatar.roblox.com/v1/users/${item}/avatar`).then(res => res.json().catch(err => { })).then(avatar => {
                avatar.assets.forEach(a => {
                  if (badassets[a.id] != undefined) {
                    comped_detected = true
                                                            }
                })
                fetch("https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/" + item + "/assets/collectibles?sortOrder=Asc&limit=100").then(res => res.json().catch(err => { })).then(p => {
                  // clog(p)
                  var amt = 0
                  if (p.data) {
                    p.data.forEach(l => {
                      amt = amt + itemdata[l.assetId][4]
                      })
                    if (amt < 5000) {
                      comped_detected = true
                    }
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  )}
  }
}

client
    .login(token)
    .catch(consola.error)
  });
```

Again sorry if this sounds very dumb, I just started Javascript (node). Oh and one more thing! I am trying for it to work on discord with a discord command. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you're using intents, I assume you're using discord.js v13. The `client.on("message"` in that case would be `client.on("messageCreate"`.

You don't need to input node index.js in repl.it. Instead, go to the 3 dots on your file like below and click on "Show Hidden Files". Once you see the `.replit` file, go into it and write on the first line: `run = "npm start"`. Then, go into `package.json` (not `package-lock.json`) and write the code on the other screenshot (I highlighted the code so it's easier for you to read). That should fix all your problems! If you need additional reference, I have pasted some very helpful YouTube tutorials that I definitely recommend to watch.

[Tutorial - Command handler and help command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KVGyUemRy0&t=3s)

[Tutorial - How to use Discord.js v13 in repl.it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWxiFUFSMB0&t=3s)

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot#2]

[image: screenshot#3]

Comment: It does the same thing :(

Comment: You don't need to type in the shell if you do it right. It should automatically start all the processes when you click run. Also, watch the tutorials and follow those instructions. They really help.

Comment: If you want some of my codes as reference I can provide the link. @user18383426

Comment: Yes please I do need a link

Comment: [code link](https://replit.com/@panzer-chan/panzerbotV2#index.js) that's my code you can reference on. Please note that I'm still trying to improve my code, and some of it may be bugged. @user18383426

Comment: I got my very first bot up and Ready!! You're the best Thank you so so much!

Comment: No problems! If you need any help with your bot, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be in the form:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const {token} = require('./token.json');
var jsonconfig = require("./config.json")
var jsonconfig,DISCORD_ID
var CMDS = jsonconfig.CMDS

var prefix = 'p!'
client.on("message", message => {
 // stuff
})
```

so basically it seems to attach some kind of listener, and then reaches the end. So it does nothing...

Comment: so what do i do? @vincent

Comment: You need to read the doc for discord.js to know how to use the library. Here is an example: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file